# How to get Order key for creating custom order return url in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders

This is the code that I am using to get a custom Order return URL:

```
global $woocommerce;
$test_order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$test_order_key = $test_order->order_key;
$returnURL = site_url().'/checkout/order-received/7140/'.$test_order_key;
```

The example URL that I need is: 
`http://www.example.com/checkout/order-received/[order_number]/key=[wc-order-key]`

How do I get **`[wc-order-key]`**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 ways to get the order key:

1) From an instance of **`WC_Order`** object class using the method [**`get_order_key()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_order_key), this way:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order_obj = WC_get_order($order_id);

// Get the order key
$order_key = $test_order->get_order_key();
$returnURL = site_url().'/checkout/order-received/'.$order_id.'/'.$order_key;
```

2) Using the WordPress [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function from the **`$order_id`**, this way:

```
// Get the order key
$order_key = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_key', true);
$returnURL = site_url().'/checkout/order-received/'.$order_id.'/'.$order_key;
```

*The Order number is the Order ID in general…*

Answer (score 0):

to get the woocommerce order received url, you can use this build-in function:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
```

plus there is a filter for the url:

```
add_filters('woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url', 'so44455859_woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url');

function so44455859_woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url($url) {
    //your logic

    return $url;
}
```