# WooCommerce get order_key

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have this code:

```
function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    $this->write_log( 'Process payment: ' . $order_id );
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    return array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'redirect' => add_query_arg( 'order', $order->id, add_query_arg( 'key', $order->order_key, get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'pay' ) ) ) )
    );
}
```

But WC says that it's incorrect of getting order_key, anybody can help me to what is the correct code for getting order_key?

thanks in advance

Comment: where do you want to show order_key?

Comment: Hi Pullata,

First of all, thanks. well I have updated the woocommerce version and I have skipped some syntax errors indicating that I have "deprecated" code, and one of the codes that indicate is that the way I have in the code to retrieve the order_key should no longer be done like this from WC +3.0

I understand that instead of doing "order-> order_key" I should do "order-> get_order_key ()" but I tried and I have code errors, and hence my question. What would the code I put in the question with the WC update be like? to avoid compatibility issues.

Comment: Actually first of you have to get an `order id` based on `order id` you can get `order_key` for example : `$test_order = wc_get_product($order_id);
$test_order_key = $test_order->get_order_key();` if you need further help I would like to know where do you want to display this key or where do you want retreive this key according to your usage i can help you in coding to get `order_key`

Comment: mmmmm i don't know if I understand you, sorry ;-)

This code it's correct, with the modifications that you said me?

`function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    $this->write_log( 'Process payment: ' . $order_id );
    $order = wc_get_product( $order_id );
    return array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'redirect' => add_query_arg( 'order', $order->id, add_query_arg( 'key', $order->get_order_key(), get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'pay' ) ) ) )
    );
}`

Comment: please `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455859/how-to-get-order-key-for-creating-custom-order-return-url-in-woocommerce/#answer-44468179` check this it may help you

Comment: can you please try this `function process_payment( $order_id ) {
 global $woocommerce,$product;
$test_order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$test_order_key = $test_order->order_key;
  $this->write_log( 'Process payment: ' . $order_id ); 
  return array( 'result' => 'success', 'redirect' => add_query_arg( 'order', $order->id, add_query_arg( 'key', $test_order_key, get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'pay' ) ) ) ) );
   }`

Answer (score 0):

If you have **order_ID** than you can use this to get order key
please try this hopefully it will help you

```
$test_order = wc_get_product($order_id);
$test_order_key = $test_order->get_order_key();
```